# Uncaught typeError: Cannot read property 'owlCarousel' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, slider

I am having a jQuery Issue, Understand I am no jQuery expert so bear with me. I am trying to install this Owl Responsive slider on magento and I am having an issue with this "

> Uncaught typeError: Cannot read property 'owlCarousel' of null in Chrome console

[image: Screenshot of Uncaught typeError: Cannot read property 'owlCarousel' of null]

Thanks.

Comment: `$('#owl-demo')` is null. Check first in console if this element exists.

Comment: @Coderaemon yes the element #owl-demo does exist!

Comment: at document ready #owl-demo should exist so that handler can be attached to it. Are you generating #owl-demo dynamically?

Answer (score 4):

By default magento use `prototypejs` framework which uses `$` as global variable. if you include other javascript plugins like jQuery which also use `$` as global variable, there will be a clash in variables related to prototypejs and jquery. This conflict can be resolved by assigning different name to global variable of jquery plugin.

To do that, use the following code above in all files wherever you are planning to use jQuery instead of prototype.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

That means you should use `jQuery` instead of `$`. Something like this:

```
jQuery("#owl-demo");
```

Comment: I already added the noConflict() to jQuery this issues is already resolved. I need to figure out why I'm getting is Uncaught typeError: Cannot read property 'owlCarousel' of null

Comment: When you've added noConflict() then `$` isn't jQuery anymore. Use `jQuery('#owl-demo')` instead to select the element.

Comment: If you guys would look at the screenshot you would see that the element is there
[link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/695g52su2go0ufe/Screen%20Shot%202014-06-10%20at%2010.43.47%20AM.png

Comment: @dlaxar No way dude, your awesome. I removed `jQuery(document).ready(function())`
and it works. Thanks a million man.!