# Uncaught Type Error - Cannot read property 'owlcarousel' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magento

This question has been asked before but after following the advice given I still have the same problem.
[Uncaught typeError: Cannot read property 'owlCarousel' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129993/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-owlcarousel-of-null)

I have a Magento store using a template called Ultimo. I want to duplicate the brands slider on the homepage to show credentials. The slider uses Lazy Owl and I've pasted the CSS, jQuery and html into my CMS Homepage only no matter what I do i.e. using jQuery instead of $ or adding noConflict the problem persists.

Website is [www.lifestylemedicine.co.uk](http://www.lifestylemedicine.co.uk)

The code is:

```
<style>
#owl-demo .item{
background: #3fbf79;
padding: 30px 0px;
margin: 10px;
color: #FFF;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
text-align: center;
}
.customNavigation{
text-align: center;
}

.customNavigation a{
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var owl = $("#owl-demo");

owl.owlCarousel({
  items : 10, //10 items above 1000px browser width
  itemsDesktop : [1000,5], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
  itemsDesktopSmall : [900,3], // betweem 900px and 601px
  itemsTablet: [600,2], //2 items between 600 and 0
  itemsMobile : false // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option
});

// Custom Navigation Events
$(".next").click(function(){
owl.trigger('owl.next');
})
$(".prev").click(function(){
owl.trigger('owl.prev');
})
$(".play").click(function(){
owl.trigger('owl.play',1000); //owl.play event accept autoPlay speed as     second parameter
})
$(".stop").click(function(){
owl.trigger('owl.stop');
})

});
</script>
<h3 class="section-title padding-right">OUR CREDENTIALS</h3>
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
<div class="item"><h1>1</h1></div>
<div class="item"><h1>2</h1></div>
<div class="item"><h1>3</h1></div>
<div class="item"><h1>4</h1></div>
<div class="item"><h1>5</h1></div>
<div class="item"><h1>6</h1></div>
<div class="item"><h1>7</h1></div>
<div class="item"><h1>8</h1></div>
<div class="item"><h1>9</h1></div>
<div class="item"><h1>10</h1></div>
</div>

<div class="customNavigation">
<a class="btn prev">Previous</a>
<a class="btn next">Next</a>
</div>
```

I'd be grateful for some help.

Comment: sounds like you have not included the *owlCarousel* script or did so too late

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if you load the js file before doing this:

```
owl.owlCarousel({
  items : 10, //10 items above 1000px browser width
  itemsDesktop : [1000,5], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
  itemsDesktopSmall : [900,3], // betweem 900px and 601px
  itemsTablet: [600,2], //2 items between 600 and 0
  itemsMobile : false // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option
});
```

The inclusion of the library should look like the following:

```
<!-- Include js plugin -->
<script src="assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

Don't forget you need Jquery library also.